# How to edit strings in place in ChunkedArray<StringType> Rust Polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'd like to do something like:

```
acc.str()?
    .iter()
    .map(|x| {
         x.push_str("AA");
    })
```

But the `x` is a `Option<&str>`, not `String`.

I read API docs and it seems that there is no way to extract `String` instead of `&str`.

Is there any way to modify the `String`s in a `ChunkedArray` in-place?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the intended functionality by using [`apply_to_buffer` API](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.apply_to_buffer).

> ```
> pub fn apply_to_buffer<'a, F>(&'a self, f: F) -> ChunkedArray<StringType>
> where
>     F: FnMut(&'a str, &mut String),
> ```
>
> Utility that reuses an string buffer to amortize allocations. Prefer
> this over an apply that **returns an owned String**.

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let df = df! (
        "groups" => &["AB", "AB", "BA", "CB", "BC"],
    )
    .unwrap();
    let chunked_array = df.column("groups").unwrap().str().unwrap();
    let modified_chunked_array = chunked_array.apply_to_buffer(|val: &str, buf: &mut String| {
        write!(buf, "{}{}", val, "AA").unwrap();
    });
    println!("{:?}", modified_chunked_array);
}
```

This will print

```
shape: (5,)
ChunkedArray: 'groups' [str]
[
        "ABAA"
        "ABAA"
        "BAAA"
        "CBAA"
        "BCAA"
]
```

See also:

- [Edit string in place with a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320653/6699447)